# PairDStreamFunctions.mapWithState fails in case timeout is set java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

Tags: sparkcore

hi i am using mapwithstate api with timeout functionality and  i am getting below mentioned exception when timeout interval hits for ideal data

i am using example located here at this location https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount.java

but some changes done: 
 1. org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional class is not available in 1.6 so i am using guava library for Optional
2. i have used timeout fucnctionality

below is part of code :

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordsDstream = words.mapToPair(
        new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
          @Override
          public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
            return new Tuple2<>(s, 1);
          }
        });


**// Update the cumulative count function
Function3<String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>> mappingFunc =
    new Function3<String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
      @Override
      public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String word, Optional<Integer> one, State<Integer> state) {


        int sum = one.or(0) + (state.exists() ? state.get() : 0);
        Tuple2<String, Integer> output = new Tuple2<>(word, sum);
        state.update(sum);
        return output;
      }
    };


// DStream made of get cumulative counts that get updated in every batch
JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, Integer, Integer, Tuple2<String, Integer>> stateDstream =
wordsDstream.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunc).initialState(initialRDD).timeout(new Duration(1000) ));**
```

when i ran above mentioned code i was getting below mentioned exception

```
16/02/25 11:41:33 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 157.0 (TID 22)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$3.apply(StateSpec.scala:222)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$3.apply(StateSpec.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(StateSpec.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(StateSpec.scala:179)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$$anonfun$updateRecordWithData$2.apply(MapWithStateRDD.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$$anonfun$updateRecordWithData$2.apply(MapWithStateRDD.scala:69)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$.updateRecordWithData(MapWithStateRDD.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDD.compute(MapWithStateRDD.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/02/25 11:41:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 157.0 (TID 22, localhost): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$3.apply(StateSpec.scala:222)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$3.apply(StateSpec.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(StateSpec.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(StateSpec.scala:179)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$$anonfun$updateRecordWithData$2.apply(MapWithStateRDD.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$$anonfun$updateRecordWithData$2.apply(MapWithStateRDD.scala:69)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$.updateRecordWithData(MapWithStateRDD.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDD.compute(MapWithStateRDD.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/02/25 11:41:33 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 157.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/02/25 11:41:33 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1456380693000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 157.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 157.0 (TID 22, localhost): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$3.apply(StateSpec.scala:222)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$3.apply(StateSpec.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(StateSpec.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(StateSpec.scala:179)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$$anonfun$updateRecordWithData$2.apply(MapWithStateRDD.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$$anonfun$updateRecordWithData$2.apply(MapWithStateRDD.scala:69)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$.updateRecordWithData(MapWithStateRDD.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDD.compute(MapWithStateRDD.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, i was directly using timeout functionality,
timeout functionality require some change in mapping function that is passed to mapWithState below is the mapping function we need to use

```
   Function4<Time, String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Optional<Tuple2<String, Integer>>> mappingFunc=
                new Function4<Time, String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Optional<Tuple2<String, Integer>>>() {

                @Override
                public Optional<Tuple2<String, Integer>> call(Time arg0,
                        String word, Optional<Integer> one,
                        State<Integer> state) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int sum = one.or(0) + (state.exists() ? state.get() : 0); 
                    Tuple2<String, Integer> output = new Tuple2<>(word, sum);
                    if(state.isTimingOut())
                    {

                        return Optional.of(output);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        state.update(sum);

                    }
                    return Optional.of(output);
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your issue should be fixed, see https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/11081

So you might want to try out a version containing that fix, which you could get by  cloning and building the current spark version in branch-1.6 - https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/branch-1.6

Comment: i was already using spark 1.6 and i already went through jira issue but problem was some where else in my code itself. it is fixed now , thanks